# Normalize Django Field's Value

Tags: django

I wrote a custom django field to normalize the urls our system received. However, the url will only return normalized value after reload.

```
from django.db import models

def _rewrite_internal_url(url):
    # 
    return 'http://www.google.com/1.jpg'

class NormalizedURLField(models.URLField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        value = super().to_python(value)
        return _rewrite_internal_url(value)


    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is None:
            return value

        return _rewrite_internal_url(value)

class DjangoTest(models.Model):
    url = NormalizedURLField()


instance = DjangoTest.objects.create(url="http://www.google.com/2.jpg")
print(instance.url) # still http://www.google.com/2.jpg
instance.referesh_from_db()
print(instance.url) # update to http://www.google.com/1.jpg
```

Comment: I'd suggest you assign what you return to "value".
`def to_python(self, value):
      value = _rewrite_internal_url(super().to_python(value))
      return value`
And something equivalent for from_db_value (see Docs for datetime)[https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#DateTimeField]
In your case, couldn't you use `pre_save`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have non-normalized urls saved in the `NormalizedURLField` fields, overriding `to_python` and `from_db_value` is unnecessary. Instead override `pre_save` to transform and update the value on the model instance when saving:

```
class NormalizedURLField(models.URLField):

    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        attr = super().pre_save(model_instance, add)
        rewritten = _rewrite_internal_url(attr)
        # update the value on the model instance
        setattr(model_instance, self.attname, rewritten)
        # return the rewritten value
        return rewritten
```

If you already have non-normalized values in your db that you want converted when fetching from the database then you will still want to implement `from_db_value` as you have done.